# RewriteRule on apache2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with the `Rewrite` rules. I'd like to redirect `domain.xx/example`
to `domain.xx/index.php?content=example`

This would actually work, but I also have a file named example.php in the same folder (`domain.xx/example.php`). Whenever I open `domain.xx/example`, the server opens `example.php` instead of redirecting me to `index.php?content=example`.

The `mod-rewrite` is on and works fine when I delete the `example.php` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example$ index.php?content=example [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of `MultiViews` option.

Add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are regular expressions, so you just need to remove the ending character to match both example and example.php

```
RewriteRule ^example index.php?content=example [NC,L]
```

Comment: This definitly goes into the right direction, thanks! Opening domain.xx/example now gives me a white page, while domain.xx/example.foo redirects me to the index.php file. Something is still missing...but I'm getting there :)

Comment: Do you have an actual folder named '/example'?

Comment: This is the uctual page I'm talking about: http://neu.bitcoinschweiz.org/news the url should redirect to index.php?content=news

Comment: You're getting a 500 error on that page - I'd check the apache error log and see what the problem is.

Comment: There's nothing in the error log regarding this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

add this to your htaccess file:

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

so the example.php will be served directly, then add your rule.

Comment: Actually, this seems to do the oposite of what I need. The file example.php does exist, but I don't wana open it. The server should redirect to index.php?content=example instead of opening the example.php